# TextMate: remember files/folder last open

Tags: macos, mac, textmate

How do I get TextMate to remember and load the files/folders I used in the last running instance?

Comment: Strange. I can't find an option for this but I can confirm that it opens up both files and projects from the last session for me. The [TextMate Manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_multiple_files) suggests that this only works for saved projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving a project will help you out with your question.  You also should take a look at the [ProjectPlus](http://ciaranwal.sh/2008/08/05/textmate-plug-in-projectplus) Plug-in.  It has a preference that tells TM to remember the entire project tree state.